# How can I read a complex number with MATLAB in a file

Tags: matlab, complex-numbers

I need read values of a txt file with MATLAB, the file is here:

```
-0.933475 0.358642
-1 6.12323e-17
```

but I have some troubles with this value `6.12323e-17`, in matlab when I read it, the vale is `0.0000`

here is the MATLAB code:

```
close all; clear;
arquivo = fopen('fftOut.txt');
formatSpec = '%f %f';
sizeA = [2 inf];
X = fscanf(arquivo,formatSpec, sizeA);
X'
fclose(arquivo);
```

and the output is

```
   -0.9335    0.3586
   -1.0000    0.0000
```

How can I handle it `0.0000`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Technically, 0.0000 is correct since your exponent is -17. Have you tried looking at the value before it is printed out? Or try changing the format.

Comment: Hi @physics90 so if I understood, don't have any error?

Comment: @physics, you are correct, I tried change the value to 6.12323e2 and the result is 612.3230.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using %f which is fixed point. Use %e for exponential notation. Check out mathwork’s web site: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html?refresh=true

Comment: yes %f also work, but show only four decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 0, when matlab prints a matrix, it uses the same notation for all elements, so the printed value is truncated but the stored one isn't.

Try printing just the imaginary part of the second number.

Comment: The number 6,12323e-17 is 0.0000000000000000612323. Fixed point formatting only shows the first 4 decimal places: 0.0000.

Comment: @physics90 IO functions do use fp formatting, but Matlab default display prints scientific notation for the maximum element.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of his formatSpec = %f %f?

Comment: Telling matlab how to parse the ascii input. It could have more complex delimiters, but dlmread works just fine in this case.

Comment: Also, a matlab matrix can't have two data types, so even with a %i spec, the result would be a double matrix.